# How can I log a header value in camel using spring DSL

Tags: java, apache-camel

This seems like it should be simple, pardon the pun. I'm trying to log a header in camel within a spring DSL route. I've seen the answer for [Java DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111044/how-to-access-get-camel-header-in-java-dsl) but I've been searching in vain for how to make it work in spring DSL. I've tried:

```
 <log message="ftping $simple{header.CamelFileName}"/>
```

and also:

```
 <log message="ftping ${header.CamelFileName}"/>
```

and several other permutations/variations, but all of them simply log that text verbatim (i.e. they do not substitute the actual header name).

What am I missing?

---

**update:** here's a larger portion of my xml file:

```
<split>
    <simple>${body}</simple>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
        <simple>${body.batchNumber}.xml</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <log message="SLH - 5 -- marshalling an EFileBatch to XML" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
    <marshal>
        <jaxb prettyPrint="true" contextPath="generated.gov.nmcourts.ecitation"
                partClass="generated.gov.nmcourts.ecitation.NMCitationEFileBatch"
                partNamespace="EFileBatch" />
    </marshal>

    <log message="SLH - 6 -- xslt transform to add schema location" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
    <to uri="{{addSchemaLocationXsltUri}}"/>

    <log message="SLH - 7 -- ftp now initiating" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
    <log message="ftping ${headers.CamelFileName}"/>

    <to uri="{{ftpOdysseyInputPath}}"/>
    <log message="SLH - 8 -- ftp now complete" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
</split>
```

Comment: What Camel version do you use?

Comment: Using camel 2.11.1 -- I suspect this is something to do w/ the fact that I'm using camel & spring properties (both)? My spring props I can reference using syntax such as: #{springprops['tylerAgency']} and my camel props I can reference using syntax such as: {{ftpOdysseyInputPath}}. Perhaps the use of spring props makes this an issue, I've read through the various camel / spring properties docs, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Asked this question some time back, and realized that I eventually found the answer so should post it here in case someone else finds this thread in a search. This works:

```
<log message="ftping $simple{in.header.CamelFileName}" loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try the following, either will work:

```
<log message="ftping ${header[CamelFileName]}"/>
<log message="ftping ${headers.CamelFileName}"/>
```

The `$simple{...}` syntax was added in Camel 2.5 to avoid clashes with Spring `${...}` - it might be that you're using an older version?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but neither of those work for me; using camel version 2.11.1. Updating my original question to show a larger snippet of my spring DSL xml file.

Comment: Camel 2.17, `" ... ${header.CamelFileName}"` works for me.

Answer (score 7):

In JAVA DSL

```
from("logger")
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${in.headers.CamelFileName}")
.end
```

LoggingLevel is from org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel

Answer (score 1):

One way that I could acomplish that (using Java DSL) was:

```
from("logger")
.log("${exchange.getIn().getHeader(\"<HEADER>\").toString()}")
.end
```

Where "<HEADER>" should be replaced by any header key that you want like "Authorization":

```
from("logger")
.log("${exchange.getIn().getHeader(\"Authorization\").toString()}")
.end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible

http://camel.apache.org/logeip.html

Difference between log in the DSL and Log component
The log DSL is much lighter and meant for logging human logs such as Starting to do ... etc. It can only log a message based on the Simple language.

On the other hand Log component is a full fledged component which involves using endpoints and etc. The Log component is meant for logging the Message itself and you have many URI options to control what you would like to be logged.