# How to log messages in Camel Spring DSL?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm using Camel 2.9.2 and defined OnCompletion route as follow:

```
            <onCompletion onFailureOnly="true">
            <log message="Nack On Failure:Status=$simple{header.CXAckStatus}:Error=$simple{header.CXAckError}" loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>
            <process ref="ackMessageProcessor" />
            <to uri="file://{{file.writer.dir}}"/>                      
           </onCompletion>
```

Provided in
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877562/how-can-i-log-a-header-value-in-camel-using-spring-dsl](http://here) solution for some reason doesn't work for me.

I can see some Camel traces relating to route definition `Line 5309: 2017-07-28 11:14:53,830 DEBUG [Thread-11] (RouteService.java:311) - Starting child service on route: writingRoute -> OnCompletionProcessor[UnitOfWork(UnitOfWork(RouteContextProcessor[Pipeline[[Channel[Log(writingRoute)[Nack On Failure:Status=$simple{header.CXAckStatus}:Error=$simple{header.CXAckError}]], Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[log://'Ack On Success:Status=$simple{header.CXAckStatus}:Error=$simple{header.CXAckError}' ])],` 
but there is no actual logged message with header values to be found...

Is anything else I need to configure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve]. What is `<to uri=""... />` suppose to be?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, http://camel.apache.org/simple.html.

$simple{} is for versions before 2.9.2. and ${} thereafter.